# Unlike and Not Unlike

Tags: grammar, synonyms

> He doesn’t eat a lot like her.

This can mean both she eats a lot and she doesn’t eat a lot, right?

> He doesn’t eat a lot unlike her.

Does this have the same problem as the first sentence?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meaning of: Tom does not have the book, like Sam](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/173920/meaning-of-tom-does-not-have-the-book-like-sam)

Comment: OK. Thanks. Now I want answers only about “unlike and not unlike”

Comment: I'm disinclined to use the search function for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (He doesn’t eat a lot like her) This can mean both she eats a lot and she doesn’t eat a lot, right?

No. As written, this sentence's primary interpretation is that she eats a lot and he doesn't; "eat a lot like her" is a [verb phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verb_phrase).

In order to state that she also does not eat a lot, there should be a comma separating "like her", similar to a slight pause in the spoken sentence. This would clearly make the phrase "like her" stand out as a [relative clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_relative_clauses), separate from the main clause.

Note that in speech, the pause/comma may be missed, so there is a potential ambiguity in this sentence. Grammatical English sentences can be ambiguous, but it should be avoided if possible.

Better alternatives to this sentence could be

- Like her, he doesn't eat a lot. *(they both don't eat a lot)*
- He doesn't eat a lot like she does. *(she eats a lot)*

> (He doesn’t eat a lot unlike her) Does this have the same problem as the first sentence? *(edited question)*

This is less likely to cause ambiguity, because "eat a lot unlike her" is not a valid verb phrase. I'd still say a comma is required to separate the main clause "he doesn't eat a lot" from the relative clause "unlike her".

Even better would be "unlike her, he doesn't eat a lot".

Comment: Sorry. I’ll make “him” “her” and please explain more about “unlike”.